# Issue with BigeDecimal value deserialization

Tags: java, csv, serialization, deserialization

I am using jsefa 0.9.2 to de-serialise CSV data. During this I encounter a issue with BigeDecimal data.
When you pass letter between numbers. de-serialisation just ignore the values after letter and return the numeric value does not raise any error. I expected not compatible error. Any suggestions to fix this issue? Code sample given below.

FoEg "123.3q21" becomes 123.3

org.jsefa
 jsefa
 0.9.2

```
    package com.jsefa;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.jsefa.common.validator.BigDecimalValidator;
    import org.jsefa.csv.annotation.CsvDataType;
    import org.jsefa.csv.annotation.CsvField;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @CsvDataType()
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        public static final String csvHeading = "Name,BirthDate,Weight";
        @CsvField(pos = 1)
        String name;

        @CsvField(pos = 2, format = "dd.MM.yyyy")
        Date birthDate;

        @CsvField(pos = 3, validatorType = BigDecimalValidator.class)
        BigDecimal weight;

        public Person() {

        }

        public Person(String name, Date birthDate, BigDecimal weight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Date getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
        }

        public BigDecimal getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + ", birthDate=" + birthDate + ", weight=" + weight + "]";
        }
    }




package com.jsefa;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsefa.csv.CsvDeserializer;
import org.jsefa.csv.CsvIOFactory;
import org.jsefa.csv.config.CsvConfiguration;

public class CSVDeSerTest {

    public CSVDeSerTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*********** CsvDeserializer *****************");
        String p = "Person,12.06.2014,123.3q21";
        List<Person> pList = deserializeSites(p.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Person:" + '\n' + pList);
    }

    private static List<Person> deserializeSites(byte[] buffer) {
        List<Person> returnList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration();
        csvConfig.setFieldDelimiter(',');
        csvConfig.setLineBreak("\n");
        csvConfig.setQuoteCharacter('\"');

        CsvDeserializer deSerializer = (CsvDeserializer) CsvIOFactory.createFactory(csvConfig, Person.class).createDeserializer();
        String persons[] = new String(buffer).split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(persons[i] + "\n");
            System.out.println("ReaderValue:" + persons[i]);
            deSerializer.open(reader);
            if (deSerializer.hasNext()) {
                Person p = deSerializer.next();
                System.out.println(p);
                returnList.add(p);
            }
            deSerializer.close(true);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the known behavior of Java's NumberFormat and related classes.

In general, if you attempt to parse a String as a Number, and the String contains a valid number format followed by garbage, the parse will be successful, the valid part will be used, and the garbage will be ignored.

I'm not familiar with jsefa, but I think it's a good bet that it's using the built-in number parsing, e.g. the BigDecimal(char[]) constructor to parse numbers. So, I'd guess that you'd have to sub-class some of the jsefa classes, and add the format checks that you want.